# Code is unreachable but I have no return function

Tags: python-3.x, function, unreachable-code

This is my first post so I am sorry if I make any mistakes writing this. So I'm making a calculator program as my first personal program after learning enough on how to code with python. But I ran into a problem when adding the functions.

When I started the making them, the code was unreachable. I am not sure how to explain more than to show you the code. I have tried removing some code, and using global functions (which I still don't really fully understand).

```
import math

i = 101
j = 102
num_1 = 0
num_2 = 0
operator = 'x'

while True:
    begin = input("Welcome to calculator. Type start to begin, and q to quit ")
    if begin == 'start':
        num_1 = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
        num_2 = float(input("Enter the second number: "))
        operator = input("Enter the function ('*' for multiplication,\n '/' for division,\n '+' for addition,\n '-' for subtraction. (Case Sensitive))")
        if operator == "*":
            print("Filler")
        if operator == "/":
            print("Filler")
        if operator == "+":
            Add()
        if operator == "-":
            print("Filler")
    elif begin == 'q':
        print("quitting program...")
        exit()
    else:
        print("You must type 'start', or 'q'(Case sensitive)")

def Add():
    answer = num_1 + num_2
    print(answer + "is your answer.")
```

I am sorry if the code is messy, as I said this is my first program and I haven't really looked on how to style it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can define the `Add()` function before it is called.

Please try the following:

```
import math

def Add():
    answer = num_1 + num_2
    print(answer + "is your answer.")

i = 101
j = 102
num_1 = 0
num_2 = 0
operator = 'x'

while True:
    begin = input("Welcome to calculator. Type start to begin, and q to quit ")
    if begin == 'start':
        num_1 = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
        num_2 = float(input("Enter the second number: "))
        operator = input("Enter the function ('*' for multiplication,\n '/' for division,\n '+' for addition,\n '-' for subtraction. (Case Sensitive))")
        if operator == "*":
            print("Filler")
        if operator == "/":
            print("Filler")
        if operator == "+":
            Add()
        if operator == "-":
            print("Filler")
    elif begin == 'q':
        print("quitting program...")
        exit()
    else:
        print("You must type 'start', or 'q'(Case sensitive)")
```